# loosing values for members of a class in a collection when calling a .net wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf, collections

I noticed that the function that calls the WCF service does not receive all of the values that are populated by the service function.

When I inspect the return from the function on the service side, the values for each member are contained within the list of objects, however, when I inspect the receiving variable on the client, the value received is for only one of the members, the values for the other members are null.

The amount in the collection is right, but the values are lost.

I noticed that the reference.cs for the service has the return type defined as an array instead of a list of objects. Would this have anything to do with it?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Your question could really do with some specifics (read - code). For example, what is the operation signature you're trying to consume? Additionally, what is it exactly that leads you to suspect the array as the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen if DataContract definition on service has changed and you have not updated your proxy. Try re-generating or updating your proxy client. In addition, check whether all the classes and their properties are correctly marked with [DataContract] and [DataMember] attributes.

Comment: That is correct Rohit, thanks for your answer! I found out that the DataMember decorator was missing from the contract specification